# why the sub domain request always redirect to another one in nginx

Tags: nginx

when I access the `chat.example.com`, the request always redirect to `www.example.com`. This is my nginx conf in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user  root;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  120;
    client_max_body_size 20m;
    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen       127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name  www.example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    server {
        listen       0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name  www.example.com;
       # return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

}
```

and this is the sub domain config in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/chat.conf` :

```
        listen       80;
        server_name  chat.example.com;
        #rewrite ^(.*)$ https://${server_name}$1 permanent;

        location / {
                client_max_body_size 1m;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_read_timeout 3600;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        }
}
```

when I using curl, the result shows like this:

```
➜  ~ curl chat.example.com/chat
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Comment: You have two forms of the `listen` directive. Two with an IP address and one without. If Nginx finds a match in a `listen` directive with an IP address, it will not consider `listen` directives without an address. For best results use consistency in your `listen` statements.